# I cannot go to a new View after logging in with FBLoginView

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift

I have tried many different ways to figure out a solution, and have been stuck for hours. I want my app to take me to a tableviewcontroller which I created in storyboard after the user logs in with Facebook, however after the user logs in, the app takes me right back to the loginviewcontroller, instead of the tableview controller. Here is my code for calling the tableviewcontroller. "cardFeed" is the identifier for the tableviewcontroller.:

`func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView: FBLoginView!) {

```
    if (FBSession.activeSession().isOpen) {
        /*var cardFeedTableViewController: AnyObject! = CardFeedTableViewController()

        cardFeedTableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("cardFeed")
        */


        let cardFeedTableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("cardFeed") as CardFeedTableViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cardFeedTableViewController, animated: true)

        println("hello")

    }
}`
```

Comment: Are you definitely using a UINavigationController?

Comment: I have a navigation controller in the tableviewcontroller, but not on the starting viewcontroller (the login view)

Comment: Then you can't use the navigation controller to push the view controller since it hasn't been created yet. You can either use a segue or present the view controller modally.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Delegate method of FBLoginView named

`- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView`

// Implement the loginViewShowingLoggedInUser: delegate method to modify your app's UI for a logged-in user experience

Write your code for navigation here...